# Replace custom tags with image tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to insert an image using a plain text editor from users
The syntax for my custom tags is

```
[^img]www.uploadedimage.com/image.jpg[$img]
```

which needs to be converted into

```
<img src="www.uploadedimage.com/image.jpg" />
```

I found the following regex to be successful

```
var re = /\[\^img\](.+?)\[\$img\]/g;
var userInput="[^img]www.uploadedimage.com/image.jpg[$img]"
var newstr = userInput.replace(re, "<img src=\"$1\"  />");
```

I want to know if I am doing it right or is there a flaw in it....or even if to use regex for this purpose or not..if not what could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That looks terrific.**

- **Overall.** In my view, you don't need to change a thing... or perhaps the `+` vs `*` I'll explain below.
- **The Capture.** For the capture, your other option is to use `([^\[]+)` instead of `(.+?)`. That would match any character that is not an opening square bracket (the beginning of your `[$img]` delimiter). The theoretical "benefit" is that there would be less backtracking (the lazy dot-star causes the engine to backtrack at each step). But really... On a modern machine, it doesn't matter.
- **The Quantifier.** You do realize that if your image tag is empty, nothing will get replaced, right? That's because your `+` needs to match one or more characters. If that's a problem, use a `*` rather than a `+`, as the `*` will match zero characters or more.

Well done!